# Writing a Factorial function in one line in Python

Tags: python, function, lambda, python-2.x

I am looking to improve my coding by performing the same code in different ways, this not only is to help me become better at coding but also understand different people's code and their coding style. Can someone explain how I might be able to right a factorial function similar to the one posted below in one line? Also using lambda functions are welcome too.

```
def factorial(number):
    fact = 1
    for i in range(1, number + 1):
        fact *= i
    return fact
```

I know I can write this recursively but I have chosen not to do it that way.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my one-liner solution without importing anything.

```
def factorial(n: int):
    return n * factorial(n - 1) if n > 1 else 1
```

It recurses until the input number is 1, where it finally returns the result (in the case of n=0, it returns 1 since 0!=1). The solution also uses the ternary operator fit an `if...else` into one line.

Note that python has a maximum recursion, so `factorial(x)` where x >= 999 will result in a `RecursionError`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) to write a factorial function.

```
from operator import mul
# from functools import reduce # Python3 only

def factorial(x):
    return reduce(mul, range(1, x + 1), 1)

factorial(5) # 24
```

You can also import it from the `math` module which additionally raises exceptions for negative and non-integral numbers.

```
from math import factorial
```

Comment: Can you explain what the final `1` parameter is in the reduce function that you wrote? Is it to deal with `0!`?

Comment: @Ely What `reduce` does is cummulatively apply the provided function to an accumulated value and the next element in the list. To do so, you must provide an initial *accumulated value*. The last parameter is that initial value. In this specific case it is indeed what makes `factorial(0)` return `1`. You can [read the doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) for more details.

Comment: Thank you, I have used the reduce function before but never with that last parameter, thank you for that.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to YulkyTulky's answer, it is also possible to write the one liner just using Boolean logic and without an `if`.

```
factorial = lambda x : x and x * factorial(x - 1) or 1
```

The `x and x * factorial(x - 1)` part returns a value as long as x is not zero, but when x is zero, the function returns 1, ending the recursion.

```
factorial(4) # 24
```

Comment: I don’t know how it looks in Assembly but your code seems unoptimized. My approach would be `x < 2 and 1 or x * factorial(x-1)`

Comment: @Raumschifffan I take your point, as it is unnecessarily calling `factorial (1 - 1)` to return 1. I think a neater approach would be `factorial = lambda x: x - 1 and x * factorial(x - 1) or x`

Comment: Oh, yes, very neat indeed. Although I would exchange that `or x` for an `or 1` should make no difference whatsoever.

Comment: One thing to add: There's no solution for 0 even though `0 * factorial(-1)` should return 0  the factorial is still called, providing no solution due to infinite recursion.

Answer (score 1):

This would be my answer

```
factorial = lambda num: 1 if num <= 1 else num * factorial(num-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a one-line lambda function with the help of the built-in function `reduce` (although you will have to import `reduce` from `functools` if you upgrade to Python 3.x). Note that the last argument sets the initial value to `1` so that `0!` can still work:

```
lambda x: reduce(int.__mul__, range(1, x + 1), 1)
```

so that:

```
print((lambda x: reduce(int.__mul__, range(1, x + 1), 1))(4))
```

would output `24`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```py
factorial = lambda x: x if x==1 else x * factorial(x-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

So the simplest option (i think) would be to create a string that you can then evaluate using the built in eval method, so we are essentially eval('1 * 2 * 3...')

```
factorial = lambda num: eval('*'.join([str(each) for each in range(1, num + 1)]))
print(factorial(3))
```

if you would want a more formatted solution you could simply create a formatted-string with your desired format, what i mean is:

```
factorial_formatted = lambda num: '{}! = {}'.format(
num, eval('*'.join([str(each) for each in range(1, num + 1)])))

print(factorial_formatted(3))
```

output respectively would be: **6**, **3! = 6**

Answer (score 0):

**Factorials in Python**

```py
factorial = math.gamma(n + 1)
```

**Example Program**

```py
import math


def get_factorial(n):
    try:
        print(math.gamma(n + 1))
    except ValueError:
        print("Domain Error: −n /∈ ℤ")
    except OverflowError:
        print("Overflow Error")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"{e}")


n = float(input("Enter n for n! : "))
get_factorial(n)
```

*Note: works for real numbers e.g. -2.90! = 5.56*

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a little late, but you can write a one line factorial function using the assignment expression operator now.

```py
>>(f:=lambda x: x*f(x-1) if x > 1 else 1)(4)
24
```